# Cocoa: SBJSON check if field exists

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, json, field

How can I check if a field exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you get your return value, I'll assume it's a dictionary here, so you'll call

```
NSDictionary* json = [parser objectWithString:yourString error: nil];
```

Where yourString is the JSON string to parse, and parser is your SBJSON* object.  This just gives you a dictionary, so you handle it the normal way, to test if a field named "blah" exists:

```
if ([json objectForKey:@"blah"] != nil)
```

See the [reference material](https://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for NSDictionary for more information, it's just a normal dictionary object.